# Push não vai para remoto e não acusa erro

Tags: git, gitlab

Tou fazendo git push -f origin "nome do branch" e não vai de forma alguma para o repositório remoto. Sendo que não aparece erro nenhum, também alterei alguns configs de buffers, o que faço para resolver?

```
Counting objects: 267, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (192/192), done.
Writing objects: 100% (267/267), 14.28 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 267 (delta 62), reused 195 (delta 31)
```

Comment: Estranho não ter relatado nenhum erro.Tenta clona o repositório novamente e substitui seus arquivos alterados, comita e depois faz o push.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, você está tentando fazer um `push -f`, verifique se possui autorização para isso.

Segundo, seus *commits* totalizam 14MB, verifique se possui arquivos grandes e se seu repositório remoto suporta arquivos com esses tamanhos.

Verifique se seus repositórios remotos estão configurados corretamente: `git remote -v` deve exibir algo do tipo:

```
origin  git@github.com:gabrsar/dotfiles (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:gabrsar/dotfiles (push)
```

Verifique se os endereços estão corretos.

Caso tudo isso esteja correto, tente o seguinte:

Tente fazer o mesmo processo sem o `-f`, e verifique se apresenta algum erro.

O parâmetro `-v` fará um push verboso, mostrando todas as mensagens de erro. Verifique se é exibido algum erro ou aviso (warning).

Se possível cole o resultado do `git push origin nome_do_branch -fv`. para que possamos ajudar melhor.